# Filter out some entries for some users in SignalR

Tags: signalr

I'm trying to build what I call a "data feed" that uses SignalR but the key to what I want to do is that I want to filter out some data for some users based on their preferences.

So, think of a chat room where each entry has some tags e.g. fitness, baseball, etc.

If user A has baseball in his subscribed tags, the next entry that has "baseball" tag in it will be visible to User A. However, user B should not see that entry if he doesn't have "baseball" tag in his preferences.

In other words, a chat room where users do NOT see every entry but only the ones that match their tag subscriptions.

Is this possible with SignalR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [SignalR Groups](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups). Each user can join/leave different groups based on their preferences:

```
public Task JoinGroup(string tagName)
{
    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, tagName);
}

public Task LeaveGroup(string tagName)
{
    return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, tagName);
}

public Task SendMessage(string message, string tagName)
{
    Clients.Group(tagName).addChatMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: I have a follow up question: I get the concept of SignalR Groups. I see that groups allow me to "partition" my messages which solves my first requirement. The second requirement is to aggregate messages from multiple groups into a single feed. Is this possible with SignalR? For example, say one user is a member of 3 groups e.g. baseball, fitness, motorcycles. I want to create a feed for this user that sends updates in any one of these groups. How do I handle this with SignalR?

Comment: Well, all users are joining the same hub. Each users joins some groups. When the user sends a message, you have to call the SendMessage function from js for each group he wants to send that message.